# What are the CentOS/RHEL 8 equivalents of libgssglue and openjpeg-libs?

Tags: centos, rhel, rpm, repository

What are the CentOS/RHEL 8 equivalents(or name of the package which they were merged into) of `libgssglue` and `openjpeg-libs`, if any(are their functions now unsupported)? I'd greatly appreciate the answer and the method that was used to find the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `openjpeg-libs` => `openjpeg2`.

As for `libgssglue` - already since RHEL 7, it was [deprecated](https://github.com/rdesktop/rdesktop/issues/92#issue-202303062) in favor of `libtirpc`:

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 the package libgssglue has been replaced by libtirpc. In most cases, the library should no longer be required and libkrb5 can be used.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also curious, could you please tell me what you searched, or what method you used to find that page?